# How to remove words from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have done my code this far but it is not working properly with remove()..can anyone help me..

```
'''
Created on Apr 21, 2015

@author: Pallavi
'''
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input
print ("Enter Query")
str=raw_input()  

fo = open("stopwords.txt", "r+")
str1 = fo.read();
list=str1.split("\n");
fo.close()
words=str.split(" ");
for i in range(0,len(words)):
    for j in range(0,len(list)):
        if(list[j]==words[i]):
            print(words[i])
            words.remove(words(i))
```

Here is the error:

```
Enter Query
let them cry try diesd
let them try
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pallavi\workspace\py\src\parser.py", line 17, in <module>
    if(list[j]==words[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: It should be `words[i]` instead of `words(i)`. Also, don't call your variable `list` or `str` as they are also used for standard classes. (And when you have an issue, paste the error message that you have; it usually contains the solution.)

Comment: i have modified that one but still it's getting this errorEnter Query
let them cry try diesd
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pallavi\workspace\py\src\parser.py", line 17, in <module>
let
them
try
    if(list[j]==words[i]):
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Well, and what about actually showing the error? Or what you expect and what you get?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The errors you have (besides my other comments) are because you're modifying a list while iterating over it. But you take the length of the list at the start, thus, after you've removed some elements, you cannot access the last positions.

I would do it this way:

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
stopwords = ['a', 'c']
for word in list(words):  # iterating on a copy since removing will mess things up
    if word in stopwords:
        words.remove(word)
```

An even more pythonic way using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
new_words = [word for word in words if word not in stopwords]
```

Comment: any ideas as to why it doesn't work for me when I do this on my data? It still keeps the words as they previous were

Comment: well; it should work, unless you're not doing it correctly or your setup is different. If you still have the issue, consider asking a new question to give all relevent information.

Comment: One entire day of hair pulling using "similar" code as above, but forgot to iterate a copy before removing from the list... thx anyways :D

Answer (score 9):

As an observation, this could be another elegant way to do it:

```
new_words = list(filter(lambda w: w not in stop_words, initial_words))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
''' call this script in a Bash Konsole like so:    python  reject.py
    purpose of this script: remove certain words from a list of words ,
    e.g. remove invalid packages in a request-list using 
    a list of rejected packages from the logfile, 
    say on https://fai-project.org/FAIme/#
    remove trailing spaces e.g. with KDE Kate in wordlist like so:

kate: remove-trailing-space on; BOM off;
'''
with open("rejects", "r+")       as fooo   :
    stwf    = fooo.read()
toreject    = stwf.split("\n")

with open("wordlist", "r+")      as bar    :
  woL       = bar.read()
words       = woL.split("\n")

new_words = [word for word in words if word not in toreject]
with open("cleaned", "w+")       as foobar :
    for ii in new_words:
        foobar.write("%s\n" % ii)
```

Answer (score 1):

one more easy way to remove words from the list is to convert 2 lists into the set and do a subtraction btw the list.

```
words = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd']
words = set(words)
stopwords = ['a', 'c']
stopwords = set(stopwords)
final_list = words - stopwords
final_list = list(final_list)
```

Comment: `words = set(words)` will remove the duplicate from words. Might not be intended if calculating frequencies or creating word-cloud.