# Python - Remove target words from each string in a list

Tags: python

I have a list of strings for example

```
my_list = ['this is a string', 'this is also a string', 'another String']
```

And I also have a list of words I want to remove from each string in that list

```
remove = ['string', 'is']
```

I want to remove the strings in remove from my_list.

I have tried looping through each list

```
new_list = []

for i in my_list:
    for word in remove:
        x = i.replace(word, "")
        new_list.append(x)
```

But this is just returning each of the original sentences.

Comment: if you print(new_list) it will show ['this is a ', 'th  a string', 'this is also a ', 'th  also a string', 'another String', 'another String']

Comment: it might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771168/how-to-remove-words-from-a-list-in-python/29771407

Comment: this code should work keep in mind you are appending it in the new_list, in case you checked the my_list, though there is a problem that this will return a list like ['this is a ', 'th  a string', 'this is also a ', 'th  also a string', 'another String', 'another String'] which is not the desired input

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove words from a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771168/how-to-remove-words-from-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're taking each string in the list, and removing each word separately, and then appending those to `new_list`. Instead what you need to do is remove those specific words and then add it to `new_list`. This can simply be accomplished with a bit of reorganizing

```py
new_list = []

for i in my_list:
    x = i

    for word in remove:
        x = x.replace(word, "")

    new_list.append(x)
```

However, this will remove occurrences within a word, not only whole words. Removing only whole words can be accomplished with some more logic such as

```py
new_list = []

for i in my_list:
    x = i.split()

    new_list.append(" ".join(a if a not in remove else '' for a in x))
```

This one is a bit more complicated, but it's splitting each string into a list and using list comprehension to form a new list that has all the words to be removed filtered out, and then joins those together with a space. This could also possibly be done with a map. Note,  this will cause double spaces where removed words were, which can be remedied with an addition such as

```py
" ".join(a if a not in remove else '' for a in x)).replace("  ", " ")
```

Comment: Hi @Gabe, that worked perfectly except I realised that instead of a list of strings, it is one string, and the commas are actually part of the string, e.g instead of what I said above it is actually 

 `'this is a string, this is also a string, another String'`


So when I try your solution, some of the words have a comma afterwards and are not picked up (e.g 'string' is in the to remove but not 'string,').

I could easily strip all the commas, but I want to keep them. Could we remove the comma as part of the loop but keep it overall?

Comment: @JamesMeroiti  Since this is an entirely different question, you could maybe try posting it as a separate question?

Comment: @JamesMeroiti That question is a bit more complex and we probably couldn't do single line list comprehension (not without massive legibility issues) so I'd recommend posting it as another question.

Answer (score 0):

```
l1=""
l2=[]
my_list = ['this is a string', 'this is also a string', 'another String']
remove = ['string', 'is']
for i in my_list:
    l1=""
    for j in i.split():
        if j not in remove:
            l1=l1+" " +j
    l2+=[l1]        
        
print(l2)
```

Your code would give the output as  `['this is a ', 'th a string', 'this is also a ', 'th also a string', 'another String', 'another String']` (the `is` in each word gets removed too, which is not desirable.) You could use `.split()` ,as illustrated above.

The output would be :

```
[' this a', ' this also a', ' another String']
```

**EDIT:**

To get rid of spaces in each element of the list, you could run a `for` loop and use `.lstrip()`

Answer (score 0):

Running your code, I got this: `['this is a ', 'th  a string', 'this is also a ', 'th  also a string', 'another String', 'another String']`

The words are removed, but since you are iterating `remove` twice for each string, you got 2x the origion strings.

If you are actually removing words, that is, 'is' in 'is' but not in 'this', I suggest using regular expressions.

```py
import re
my_list = ['this is a string', 'this is also a string', 'another String']
pattern = re.compile(r'\s*\b(string|is)\b|\b(string|is)\b\s*')
new_list = [pattern.sub("", s) for s in my_list]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: How would we deal with space on either side?

Comment: @RazzleShazl By making the regex nastier:
`pattern = re.compile(r'\b(string|is)\b\s*|\s*\b(string|is)\b')`

Comment: Oh that's much better than I was trying to have a negative look-behind match!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job :

```
input_string = 'this is a string, this is also a string, another String'

my_list = list(input_string.split())
remove = ['string', 'is']
remove_with_comma = [str(i) + ',' for i in remove]

correct_words = my_list[:]

for word in my_list:
    if word in remove:
        correct_words.remove(word)
    elif word in remove_with_comma:
        correct_words[correct_words.index(word)] = ','

print(' '.join(correct_words))
```

Output : `'this a , this also a , another String'`

Comment: Hi @Vibhu, that worked perfectly except I realised that instead of a list of strings, it is one string, and the commas are actually part of the string, e.g instead of what I said above it is actually 'this is a string, this is also a string, another String' So when I try your solution, some of the words have a comma afterwards and are not picked up (e.g 'string' is in the to remove but not 'string,'). I could easily strip all the commas, but I want to keep them. Could we remove the comma as part of the loop but keep it overall?

Comment: @JamesMeroiti i've changed the code according to your need...have a look :)

Answer (score 0):

Another reimplementation of your solution along the same lines with just a few tweaks to get the correct result:

- Lowered the case of your annotated phrase so remove words like "String" would still match.
- Prepended a space to the remove word when replacing to avoid replacing the "is" in "this," for exampl.e

Example:

```
my_list = ['this is a string', 'this is also a string', 'another String']
remove = ['string', 'is']

annotated_list = []
for phrase in my_list:
    annotated_phrase = phrase.casefold()
    for pattern in remove:
        annotated_phrase = annotated_phrase.replace(" " + pattern, "")
    annotated_list.append(annotated_phrase)

print(annotated_list)
```

Output:

```
['this a', 'this also a', 'another']
```

Answer (score 0):

To save output in the same list:

```
 for rem in remove:
    for i,str in enumerate(my_list):
        if rem in str:
            str = str.replace(rem, '')
            my_list[i]=str
print(my_list)
```

Output: `['th  a ', 'th  also a ', 'another String']`